# Facebook shortcuts in Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome

I found this website which gives a number of shortcuts for Facebook. http://www.socialbakers.com/blog/1288-save-time-with-facebook-shortcuts

They require you to hold control and alt, which are already defined in Ubuntu. What is the best way to get around this? I am using Chromium.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply hit start and type "keyboard" and hit enter to launch the keyboard preferences app.  Then click the "Shortcuts" tab.  From this dialogue you can remap the key commands that are the issue, and then the custom Facebook, etc. commands should work.  However, it seems likely that this is a "Windows only" sort of feature, in which case the commands won't work on a Linux box.